# Como criar um evento de click que só é chamado ao clicar fora de uma div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

Preciso que ao clicar fora de uma `div` (é uma 'telinha' de cadastro), a mesma se feche.

Que seletor eu deveria usar para que clicando em qualquer parte fora da div essa div se feche?

```
$(????).on("click", function(){
    $('div').hide();  
});
```

Se houver clique em qualquer parte ou elemento da `div` não poderá fechar pois o usuário estará efetuando o preenchimento dos dados.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você pode associar o evento em um elemento mais externo, por exemplo o `body`, e dentro do evento verificar qual é o target do evento.

Se o target for a DIV que você quer excluir do evento de click, então usando um `if` não faça nada neste caso.

**javascript**

```
$(function() {
    var div = $("#div"); // seleciona a div específica
    $("body").on("click", function (e) {
        if (div.has(e.target).length || e.target == div[0])
            return;

        alert("Você clicou fora da div!");
    });
})
```

### [jsfiddle - excluindo 1 elemento do evento](http://jsfiddle.net/Nk5K5/)

**Excluindo múltiplas áreas do evento**

Usando closest como indicado por [@mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/215/mgibsonbr) fica ainda mais fácil estender o conceito: por exemplo, quando se quer excluir múltiplas áreas do evento:

### [jsfiddle - excluindo vários elementos do evento](http://jsfiddle.net/E75Hn/1/)

Comment: Eu teria que verificar também todos os elementos dentro da div. Ou estou enganado?

Comment: Você vai ter que detectar se o target é a própria div ou se possui a div como ancestral... vou criar um fiddle de exemplo.

Comment: Creio que [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) pode te ajudar nisso. Basta usar o seletor da div desejada como argumento; se retornar mais de zero resultados, é porque o elemento está dentro da div.

Comment: @mgibsonbr: com `closest` fica ainda mais flexível... no meu exemplo usei `has`... mas se tivesse que excluir múltiplos elementos do evento, o `closest` ajuda muito.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode adicionar o evento `click` no `document` disparando para todo a página.

Em um `if` dentro do `click` verificar qual o *target* do local clicado, se o ID for igual o da div dê um `return false`, caso contrário execute o `hide`.

Tem uma pegadinha, precisa ser verificado se o elemento `$(e.target)` é filho do elemento que **não** deve ter o evento click disparado.

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    var obj = 'item', id = $(e.target).attr('id');
    if (id==obj) return;
    if ($("#"+obj+" #"+id).length > 0) return;
    $("#"+obj).hide();
});
```

Olhe o exemplo no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEXCool/L5n2D/2/)

Comment: Funciona para o problema na pergunta, mas se li bem o código, se existir um evento de `click` num elemento dentro do elemento alvo, esse evento não vai disparar.

Comment: pra mim funcionou [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEXCool/L5n2D/4/) vc tem algum exemplo de como não funcionaria?

Answer (score 0):

Quando precisamos fazer alguma coisa inúmeras vezes, talvez valha a pena criar uma extensão em `jQuery`para poder resolver esse problema.

Eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.clickOut = function (callback) {

        var that = this;

        $(document).click(function (e) {

            if ( $(e.target).closest(that).size() > 0) {

                return;
            }

            $.isFunction(callback) && $.proxy(callback, that)(e);
        });
    }

})( jQuery )
```

Aí quando quero que determinado elemento seja fechado apenas quando se clica fora, faço da seguinte forma:

```
$('.fecha_quando_clica_fora').clickOut(function()
{
    $(this).hide()
});
```

Veja isso no [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wallacemaxters/c5hz7h1p/)

Comment: **Atualização** A pergunta é de 2014. Atualmente você pode usar a pseudoclasse `body:not('div')`